# Authlogic User Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, authlogic

I keep trying to find a way to associate data with users in authlogic. I've tried everything I can think of but nothing seems to grab the data I'm trying to associate with it. Does anyone have an example that they can share? I'm currently trying to grab the currently associated email like this.

UserSessionsController:

```
  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
    @current_User = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user_session }
    end
  end
```

user_sessions view:

```
<p> <%= @current_user.email %> </p>
```

application controller:

```
helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  end
```

And get this error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

about:

```
<p> <%= @current_user.email %> </p>
```

Thank you in advance for any help! It's really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in the top of your `ApplicationController` you have

```
class ApplicationController
  helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user
```

Then, in your views, don't use `@current_user`, use `current_user`.

```
<p> <%= current_user.email %> </p>
```

When you call `@current_user` in your view, it's never been set for that request, which is why you get the `nil:NilClass` error.

```
helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user
```

This makes the `current_user` method which is already available within all of your controllers extending `ApplicationController` also available in your views as a helper method. By using `current_user`, you guarantee you're being returned the current `UserSession` instance. After it's been retrieved the first time *(on the first call to `current_user`)*, `@current_user` will have a value, meaning

```
return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
```

will execute, skipping the attempt to find the current `UserSession` instance in subsequent calls to `current_user`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! That explanation was extremely clear and helpful! I really appreciate the help.